# Trying to run VMWare Workstation on Google Cloud Platform instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, vmware-workstation

**Windows:**
Now, I want to install a VMWare Workstation on the Windows Google Cloud Platform instance and next install another OS on that VMWare Workstation.

But I get this BSOD.

**Linux:**
Now, I want to install a VMWare Workstation on the Linux Google Cloud Platform instance and next install another OS on that VMWare Workstation.

But I get this error.

```
This host supports intel VT-x. but the Intel VT-x implementation is incompatible. 

This host does not support Intel EPT hardware assisted MMU virtualization.

Module "CPUIDEarly" power on failed.

Failed to start the virtual machine.
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is rather useless to install a type 2 (hosted) hypervisor inside a GCE virtual machine.

There are a) other options for VMware hosting or b)  [migrate](https://cloud.google.com/migrate/compute-engine/docs/4.5/how-to/configure-manager/configuring-vms-vm) these containers with Velostrata.

---

c) That one error message (assuming you'd go the proposed nested virtualization route) might require `monitor.allowLegacyCPU = "true"` in file `config.ini`, because it seems the CPU is not supported by VMware Workstation 14 (this at least works for some elder Intel® Xeon® CPU).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Martin that you may not want to run VMware workstation, but you may need nested virtualization for other stuff like VMware ESXi/qemu.

GCE VMs do support nested virtualization please see [Enabling Nested Virtualization for VM Instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/enable-nested-virtualization-vm-instances) on how to do it. This will enable VT-x support inside the VM.

Comment: There it reads `You can use nested virtualization on any Linux VM instance running on a Haswell or newer platform` ...so the host OS needs to be Linux for doing so.

Comment: Thats true. Linux versions should be fine. I do believe the primary use-case is to not run the desktop hypervisor but to run bare-metal hypervisors.

Comment: I'd merely wonder what would be the cost-efficiency factor, when comparing a nested virtualization with a hypervisor running on bare metal. There likely is some overhead involved or some performance trade-off.